# Linux Symlink difference

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I have a Question.

what is difference between this symlinks,
the bottom symlinks is created with

```
cp -s
```

and about top files i dont know, I want know how they symlinked.

[image]

Comment: The top files are not symlinks

Comment: thank u, so why their color is like symbolic files? they are really not symbolic? how i know they are not symbolic?

Comment: which is better? cp -s 
OR ln -s  ??

Comment: It's clearly a different color though? It is noticeably darker for the regular files. If it isn't for you, your screen could be set up incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, they are a different color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output of `info cp`:

```
‘-s’
‘--symbolic-link’
   Make symbolic links instead of copies of non-directories.  All
   source file names must be absolute (starting with ‘/’) unless the
   destination files are in the current directory.  This option merely
   results in an error message on systems that do not support symbolic
   links.
```

When executed on files, both commands are identical, although using
`cp` for creating symbolic links may not be very self-documenting.

But when executed on folders, `cp` will need to be called as
`cp -sr` and will work on the files, not on the folder,
this creating a symbolic link for each file.

Whereas `ln -s` will link the folder only and will generate only one
symbolic link.

So in the case of operating on a folder, `ln -s` will be much
more efficient. For files, both are equal as regarding efficiency
and result.

Comment: thanks, so regarding your describe if i need to symbolic all files in a folder, it's better use ln -s on folder?

Comment: Yes, very much so.